# didSelectRowAtIndexPath and performSegueWithIdentifier

Tags: swift2, segue

I have a tableView that display a list of cells. I need to catch the selected cell, and pass my object data based on `indexPath.row` to display it on my Second View Controller. My `didSelectRowAtIndexPath` is working fine, but probably I'm not familiar with the syntax for `performSegueWithIdentifier`, where it fails to call the method.

Sorry I'm new to Swift programming, would appreciate if you could explain more details.

```
func tableView(tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath){
    selectedCell = indexPath.row
    performSegueWithIdentifier("DetailScreen", sender: self)
}

override func performSegueWithIdentifier(identifier: String, sender: AnyObject?) {
    detailedView.personName = personList[selectedCell].GetPersonName()
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Solution 1**

First, make sure you have segue between your first and second view controllers (From the table view controller one to the Detail view screen). Make sure that the segue has a name

[image]

Now in your first view controller's `didSelectRowAtIndexPath` event, Invoke the segue like this.

```
performSegueWithIdentifier("DetailScreen", sender: nil)
```

Now in the `prepareForSegue` method of the first view controller, you can customize it to send more details.

```
override func prepareForSegue(segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: AnyObject?) 
{       
   if(segue.identifier=="DetailScreen")
   {
     let ctrl = segue.destinationViewController as! YourDetailsViewController
     ctrl.personName = "Set some person name here"
   }
}
```

Assuming Your Detail screen's class is called `YourDetailsViewController` and it has a property called `personName` of String type. You may update the code to use your real view controller.

**Solution 2**

If you do not want to create the segue, you can programmatically navigate( actually pushing the second view controller to the front) to the second view. In your first view controllers, didSelectIndexPathAtRow method,

```
func tableView(tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath){

  let ctrl = self.storyboard?.instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier("DetailsCtrl")
                                      as? YourDetailsViewController

  ctrl?.personName="Set some name here"

  self.navigationController?.pushViewController(ctrl!, animated: true)
}
```

For the above code to work, you need to make sure that you have StoryBoardID set to "DetailsCtrl" on the second view controller(Details view)

[image]

Comment: Hi, I followed exactly what you said, but I got this error


People_Project[1277:71769] *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: 'Receiver (<People_Project.PersonDetailScreen: 0x7ff82bd25d20>) has no segue with identifier 'DetailScreen''

Comment: Just to confirm, `performSegueWithIdentifier("DetailScreen", sender: nil)` is placed at my Second View Controller right? Because both is in different class. Which i think is the cause to the problem.

Comment: @JoeLeong See my updated answer which answers your questions

Answer (score 0):

You have set the storyboard segue as given below:

Click on the segue and add the identifier

[image]

You can achieve the above requirement using the following code and this worked for me:

```
   func tableView(tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath){
        let storyboard1 = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: nil)
                                    
        let detail = storyboard1.instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier("DetailScreen") as! SecondViewController
        detail.personName = personList[selectedCell].GetPersonName()
        self.navigationController?.pushViewController(detail, animated: true)
 }
```

The storyboard segue from your first view controller to second view controller should be "Push".

Hope this might be helpful.

Comment: set, but still the same issue.

Comment: I have updated the answer, actually your have to set the identifier of the segue.

Comment: It "does work", but its not correct. What happens is it forces the `prepareForSegue` to run going into the `if(segue.identifier == "DetailScreen")` to execute, and then in the `didSelectRowAtIndexPath` it runs `prepareForSegue` again. What I'm seeing now is physically the SecondViewController loads twice.

Comment: It still loads twice. Even when I click back, I have to click back twice. Lol!

Comment: Can your add your code to GitHub and give me the link?